# Drupal doesnot save changes

Tags: drupal

I have a drupal7 website and I have a drop down menu of products in my website.
I am able to add or rename a product in the list of the products , but when I save and go look at the drop down menu , I cannot see the changes that I just made !
I flush the cache every time I make some change . 
Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use a menu navigation made by some of your content names, if you rename your product, you have to make the change each time in admin/structure/menu/your menu/list links and modify the link name.